# C# Declare Variable in if statement, Common Base Class

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wshttpbinding, basichttpbinding

I am attempting to pass a string into a method and based on what string is passed in, either instantiate BasicHttpBinding or WSHttpBinding. The following if statement is in my code.

```
if(bindingObject == "basic")
{System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();}
else
{System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding();
```

This code gives me the error

> The name 'binding' does not exist in the current context

From my research it seems I have to use a common base class between the two service models if I want to use the variable named *binding* no matter which ServiceModel I need to use.

My question is, what is the common base class that would work? Or is there a way to do this. The closest I have found is System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding but then I get the error such as

> does not contain a definition for 'MaxBufferPoolSize' and no extension method 'MaxBufferPoolSize' accepting a first argument of tyep 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding' could be found

Comment: you can't declare a variable of different types like this.

Comment: You could refactor that if-then block into a generic method, which would then return the appropriate binding.  I.e., something like `public T GetBinding<T>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is because of scoping of local variables. According to C# specs for scoping from MSDN,

> Scopes can be nested, and an inner scope may redeclare the meaning of a name from an outer scope (this does not, however, remove the restriction imposed by §1.20 that within a nested block it is not possible to declare a local variable with the same name as a local variable in an enclosing block).

Another from spec for identifiers scoping,

> For each occurrence of a given identifier as a simple-name in an expression or declarator, within the local variable declaration space, immediately enclosing block, or switch-block of that occurrence, every other occurrence of the same identifier as a simple-name in an expression or declarator within the immediately enclosing block or switch-block must refer to the same entity. This rule ensures that the meaning of a name is always the same within a given block, switch block, for-, foreach- or using-statement, or anonymous function.

Now moving to the error you're facing:
`BasicHttpBinding` is derived from HttpBindingBase which derived from `Binding` and implement `IBindingRuntimePreferences`.
`WSHttpBinding` is dervied from WSHttpBindingBase which derived from `Binding` and implement `IBindingRuntimePreferences`.

But the property `MaxBufferPoolSize` resides in HttpBindingBase and WsHttpBindingBase and not in their common parent `Binding` or `IBindingRuntimePreferences`. Which means you can not use a common class to represent these bindings. Rather you should use `dynamic` as type which would bind the types at runtime instead of compile time.

```
Public dynamic GetBinding(string bindingObject)
 {
    if (bindingObject == "basic")
    {
        binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
    }
    else
    {
        binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding();
    }

   return binding;
  }
```

Comment: This worked with a couple of caveats. First, I had to declare a variable of dynamic binding; in the GetBinding method.  Then, I realized this was .net 3.5 code and had to convert the project to 4.0

Answer (score 1):

First:  both `BasicHttpBinding` and `BasicHttpBinding` need to either derive from the same base class or implement the same [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx)

If you're using visual studio, you can put a cursor over the types and press `f12` to see what types they derive from and what interfaces they implement.  The type that is appropriate to use depends on what you want to do with them.

According to documentation for [BasicHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [WSHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the common base class seems to be `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding`,

**You should use `f12` to check anyway, because there's probably an interface in there that defines the members that you need to use.**

Second, You have to declare it outside the context of your if statement

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding;
if(bindingObject == "basic")
{
    binding = ...
}
else
{
    binding = ...
}
```

Comment: The best common base the two classes have is `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i was just looking that up

Comment: I think OP would have to cast to the derived class to access the properties though, if they're trying to set something that one binding has and the other doesn't.

Comment: @Tim If the OP wants to use properties that are not defined in a common interface or shared instance, then it probably doesn't make sense to keep them in the same variable in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You could use wither the Binding base class or the IBindingRuntimePreferences interface, if that provides access to the functionality you need.

```
   //System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding;
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.IBindingRuntimePreferences binding;
    if(bindingObject == "basic")
       binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();}
    else
       binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perfect use case for dynamic keyword

```
        dynamic binding;
        if (bindingObject == "basic")
        {
            binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
        }
        else
        {
            binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding();
        }
```

Then you can access the following

```
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 10;
```